# How to retreive all the properties of an object which is inside another object with C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have these three tables in SQL Server:

```
Evaluations (id, textreview, stars, userId, BookId)    
Books      (id, title, ..., userId)    
Users      (id, name, ...)
```

And I have this code to get data from my tables:

```
public List<Evaluations> GetAllEvaluationsPerBook()
{
    string sqlCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT b.Title,ev.TextReview,ev.Stars, b.Id " +
                        "FROM[Services.BookDbContext].[dbo].[Evaluations] as ev, " +
                            "[Services.BookDbContext].[dbo].Books as b " +
                        "WHERE b.Id = ev.Book_Id";

    using (var context = new BookDbContext())
    {
        var evaluation = context.Evaluation.SqlQuery(sqlCommand).ToList();

        return evaluation;
    }
}
```

Now I'm creating a WebApi project in C# with EF6. I use Actions with HttpPost. In one of them I need to retrieve some objects from the DB and send them to a client such as Fiddler in json format. More specifically, I want to get the Title of the Book along with all the Evaluations.

Now I need to create the json below using the code above:

```
{"id":1,    "textReview":"Good",     "stars":3, "book":null,    "user":null},    
{"id":2,    "textReview":"Awfull",   "stars":1, "book":null,    "user":null},    
{"id":1,    "textReview":"Good",     "stars":3, "book":null,    "user":null},    
{"id":4,    "textReview":"Very Good","stars":4, "book":null,    "user":null}
```

E.G.: Below you can see the result which I receive from DB, but i cannot make it appear in json format:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dky9c.png]

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show the `Evaluation` class?

Comment: You really need to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: What version of Entity Framework do you use? I believe the syntax is `context.Database.SqlQuery<Evaluation>`

Comment: Hello all and thank u for your reply. I use Entity framework 6.

Comment: @ikerbera Unfortunately i am not able to edit my Question above, so I will give details for **Evaluation** class here:     [DataContract]
    public class Evaluations
    {
    [DataMember(Name ="id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "textReview")]
    public string TextReview { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "stars")]
    public int Stars { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "book")]
    [Required]
    public Books Book { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "user")]
   [Required]
   public Users User { get; set; }
    }

Comment: You need to change your SQL to add the Book and User information, then you have to change the resultin JSON to add that information. With the JSON you have to change the ´Books´ and ´Users´ classes so they will fill automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer which I wanted:

```
public List<Evaluations> GetAllEvaluationsPerBook()
    {
        using (var context = new BookDbContext())
        {
            var evaluations = context.Evaluation.ToList();
            var books = context.Book.ToList();
            var users = context.User.ToList();

            return evaluations;
        }
    }
```

So the code always runs line by line.
The  variable **evaluations** creates a list, filling all its own properties except the Book and the User objects which are remaining null:

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "textReview":"The Book is good.",
   "stars":3,
   "book":null,
   "user":null
}
```

After "running" the next line, it fills the list of books. But it fills also the previous list of **evaluations** with the new list of books:

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "textReview":"The Book is good.",
   "stars":3,
   "book":{  
      "isbn":1,
      "title":"The Tomb",
      "author":"H. P. Lovecraft",
      "user":null
   },
   "user":null
}
```

Finally it "runs" the line with the users, (retrieving all the users from the DB and creating a list of users) and automatically it fills the previous Lists, so I have all the information retrieved from the DataBase.

Comment: what's the purpose of `var books = context.Book.ToList()` and `var users = context.User.ToList();` if they are not being returned?

Comment: If you do not include them in your code, then the **book** object which belongs to "evaluations" remains empty. That is what I found out and I posted it in my answer above. ( **evaluations** consists of some properties. One of them is **books** object. In order to fill the **books** property you follow the code above ) :)